# ¿Como crear un objeto estático en C++?

Tags: c++

Estoy haciendo una APIS. Que me facilite la construcción de aplicaciones windows en win32 APIS. Tengo este problema:

```
Terminate called after throwing an instance of '__GNU_CXX::recursive_init_error'

what(): std::exception
This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way. Pleace contact the application's support team for more information.

Process return 255 (0xFF)
```

Que viene de:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowsProcedure(HWND hwnd....){
static button b1(hwnd);

...

}
```

Como notarán: Inicializo la clase con `hwnd` Qué es básicamente un id unico de la ventana. Y solo necesito que el b1 se declaré y que no muera.
El problema viene cuando la inicializo estática.
No me gustaría que sea global por lo que declararla estática es mi mejor opción. 
El hwnd lo obtendré en tiempo de ejecución y no cambiará durante la vida del programa.
Aquí está el código de la clase:

```
class button{
public:
    HWND hwnd;//Este es le id de la ventana
    HWND boton;//Este es el id del boton
    button(HWND hwnd2){
    hwnd=hwnd2;
    boton=CreateWindowEx(0,"button","Click Me",WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | MB_DEFBUTTON2,0,0,30,80,hwnd,(HMENU)BUTTON1,GetModuleHandle(NULL),0);
    }


};
```

Y aquí está todo completo:
[Github](https://github.com/dabl03/Windows7)

Comment: Cualquier sujerencia sobre como mejorar la pregunta son bien recivida.

Comment: Podrías poner el error en texto en vez de una imagen? Es difícil ver que pasa

Comment: No le veo mucha diferencia pero aquíva.@JhonRayo99

Comment: Listo. @JhonRayo99

Comment: @DanielBriceño estamos viejos y no vemos imágenes. El código es fácil de ver, manipular y probar :)

Comment: @Alfabravo Creo que tienes razon, pero no era código sino los errores que me salieron... Lo tendre en cuenta la proxima. Recuerda: Somos los mas viejos de lo que nunca fuímos, pero ánimo somos lo mas jovenes de lo que nunca seremos.:)

Answer (score 1):

Veamos el código:

```
int function(int hwnd,int wParam){
    static button b1(hwnd);
    // ...
}
```

Ahí estás creando un objeto estático local a la función. Los efectos son los siguientes:

- La variable `b1` solo se inicializa una vez, es decir, si creases un segundo formulario y llamases a esta función pasándole un segundo *handle*, el botón no se crearía de nuevo, seguirías teniendo un único botón con el *handle* original. Si alguien destruye ese botón tirando de su *handle*, `b1` apuntará a un botón que ya no existe.
- Como consecuencia de lo anterior, no puedes tener 2 o más botones controlados por esta función.
- No puedes controlar la vida de `b1`. Si el objeto ya no estuviese vivo tendrías que tener cuidado de no volver a invocar esta función
- ¿Qué pasaría si se invoca esta función varias veces con diferentes *handles*?

Si estás componiendo una ventana o formulario quizás sería recomendable estructurar el código para plasmar la relación entre los controles del formulario y el propio formulario:

```
class Formulario1
{
private:
    button b1;
};
```

Ahí sería el propio constructor de `Formulario1` el que se encargaría de crear e inicializar los diferentes controles contenidos en dicho formulario.

Comment: En otras palabra no se puede crear una clase estática.¿?

Comment: @DanielBriceño claro que se puede, pero solo hay que hacerlo cuando tiene sentido. Es como preguntar si se puede usar un coche... pues depende, si quieres hacer un viaje por carretera, claro, si quieres atravesar el océano... lo mismo no es la mejor opción

Comment: Nota: hwnd es una constante que antes de qué se inicie el programa no se sabe el valor y muere cuando muere el programa.

Comment: @DanielBriceño yo solo te doy pautas para que arregles los errores que te han hecho venir aquí. No has puesto un ejemplo mínimo y completo, luego solo se pueden hacer conjeturas.

Comment: Listo..........